# How can I get only 0 and 1 as results in a linear regression in sas?

Tags: sas, linear-regression

I have a linear model that predicts the stat "buy" that can only have 0 or 1 as an outcome.

All my predictions are some rational numbers like 0.2 or something like that. My idea would be to make every number of 0.5 or above a 1 and everything else a 0. How can I do that?

My idea was with an if then else statement but at least like that it doesn't work:

```
proc GLMSELECT data=tasks.data plots=all;
 by descending gender;
 model buy = affiliate age;
 if buy >=0.5 then buy = 1 else 0;
run;
```

How do I need to code it so it works?

Comment: Here's a good tutorial on logistic regression with SAS https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/stat/data/logistic_regression_sas/logistic_regression_sas.html#(1)

Comment: Did you want separate models for genders? I would recommend using that as a categorical variable in the model instead unless you believe they're different enough to warrant separate models entirely.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a linear regression model, you need a logistic regression model. Linear regression is designed for continuous outcomes, not binary events. [I highly recommend reading up about the differences between categorical and continuous models](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/12/beginners-take-how-logistic-regression-is-related-to-linear-regression/).

```
proc logistic data=sashelp.heart plots=all;
    class BP_Status Chol_Status Smoking_Status ;
    
    model status(event='Dead') = Height Weight BP_Status Chol_Status Smoking_Status 
        / selection=stepwise sle=0.1 sls=0.05
    ;
run;
```

Comment: Just adding on that logistic regression will give you a probability between 0/1 and then you can code it using IF/THEN but you should do that in a next step anyways.